# How to use c library function fgets in assembly language?

Tags: c, assembly, abi

As the title described, how to use c library function fgets in assembly language? Indeed, I want to know how to get the file pointer to stdin. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can write a simple program using fgets and compile it with gcc -S to see how to do it

Comment: I recommend repeating with various levels of optimization as well. +1